# Removing an specif item from array by its index is removing just last item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array:

```
const data = [
[name: "info", type: "input"]
[name: "exp", type: "input"]
[name: "ski", type: "input"]
]
```

and when I try to remove the selected item from array by its index, it just deletes the last one...

```
data.splice(0, 1)
//I have this mapped by I am trying to make it look shorter...
```

or if I use

```
data.filter((item, index) => {
if(index === myIndex) return true;
//this is removing only my last index, and not the index referenced by "myindex"
})
```

Comment: Your filter logic is backwards. `return true` means "keep this array item." Also your `splice()` doesn't use `myIndex` so it's unclear why that's part of your question

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to remove a specific item from an array I would recommend you to use filter() method. Though there was problem with the declaration of the data array. I assume that data is an array of objects and you can filter the data as follows:

```
data.filter((item, index) => (index !== myIndex));
```

The above code will return an array without the specific index element. If you face further problem then you can comment. The data array I assumed as follows:

```
const data = [
    {name: "info", type: "input"},
    {name: "exp", type: "input"},
    {name: "ski", type: "input"},
];
```

Comment: It is an array of arrays, not an array from objects

Comment: and I did the same but with a bigger sintaxe

Comment: Ok, it may array of arrays. This process doesn't depend on the array element, it will depend on the array index.

Answer (score -1):

actually, the issue is with your array--

an array of object elements is something that looks like this

```js
const data = [
{name: "info", type: "input"},
{name: "exp", type: "input"},
{name: "ski", type: "input"}
]
```

FYI -
[image: check this image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @AndyRay it is working when we create array like above

Comment: I know how it is an array of objects but I am doing an array of arrays...